# Modeling Tetrahedral Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Would the best way to model tetrahedral numbers be:

1. A quadratic function because the 3rd successive differences are a nonzero constant.
2. A cubic function because the 3rd successive differences are a nonzero constant.

I believe it is 2 because 3rd successive differences indicate a cubic function, but does that mean that using a cubic function is the best way to model tetrahedral numbers?

Comment: HINT: What are the first four or five tetrahedral numbers? What formula seems to fit the pattern? And can you convince yourself (from a geometric argument) that the formula is correct in general?

Comment: I would say that a cubic function best models it. I'm not sure how I would prove that, but that is what I believe due to tetrahedral numbers having 3rd successive differences.

Comment: Imagine an animation. What gets added to the picture as you go from $n$ to $n+1$?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Could  please you elaborate?

Comment: Please read [tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to observe is that as we go from the $(n-1)$st tetrahedral number to the $n$th, we add on the $n$th triangular number.
We might write this as $$T_n = T_{n-1}+t_n.$$ Well, what is that $n$th triangular number?
It’s $1+2+\cdots+n$, which Gauss found as a schoolboy to be $$t_n = \frac{n(n+1)}2,$$
and which, in turn, you should recognize as ${n+1}\choose 2$, or in words, the number of 2-element subsets of an $(n+1)$-element set. We can use this fact as the inspiration for a combinatorial derivation of the formula for $T_n$.

To do so, consider a small example, $t_4$.
What’s a good way to conceive of $1+2+3+4$ as the number of 2-element subsets of a $(4+1)$-element set? Picture this scene: the Beatles—John, Paul, George, and Ringo—are in a recording session with Mick Jagger. They want to record a track requiring a duet. How many duos can they form? Well, if Mick is involved, he could be paired  with any of the Fab Four. If he isn’t, then it could be John with any of the other three, or—if neither Mick nor John is included—then it could be Paul with either George or Ringo. And the last option is to pair up George and Ringo.
Hence, $${4+1 \choose2} = 4+3+2+1 = t_4,$$
as we wished to show.  And clearly with a bit of formalizing, this argument could be generalized to constitute a combinatorial proof that $t_n = {n+1\choose 2}$ for any $n\geq 1$.

So now, to proceed from the triangular numbers to the tetrahedral numbers. Since $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^n t_i$, we can ask ourselves, What’s a situation corresponding to summing up triangular numbers? Well, suppose that the following day, the Beatles and Mick are joined by Janis Joplin to record a track that includes a trio.

The number of possible triads is, of course $4+2\choose 3$. But we can also count the triads by adapting our duo logic from the day before. Consider, if the track includes Janis, then fleshing out the rest of the trio amounts to picking one of yesterday’s (no, not $Yesterday$’s) duos. Well, there are $t_4$ of those. And the triads that don’t include Janis but do include Mick number $t_3$. And those including neither Janis nor Nick number $t_2$. You get the picture. So
$${4+2\choose3} = \sum_{i=1}^4 t_i = T_4.$$
And once again, this story can easily be formalized and generalized to yield the formula you seek:
$$T_n = {n+2 \choose 3} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}.$$